# How to stop Curl from caching data

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a HTTP streaming video server that I access using a url like so:

```
https://192.168.50.23:8011/livevideo/8
```

If I paste this url in to my web browser address bar I can see live video but after a few minutes the video stops streaming.  If I kill the browser and repeat the process I can get video streaming for another few minutes before it stops again.

I figured that it must be something to do with the web browser caching the MJPEG frames and running out of memory so as an experiment I mocked up a simple HTML page like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <img src="https://192.168.50.23:8011/livevideo/8" width="500" height="500">
  </body>
</html>
```

And the result is that the vieo streams constantly and never stops.  So I guess the  tag is dealing with disposing of the MJPEG frames and not causing a crash like before.

I used FireFox to analyse the HTTP requests and responses for both scenarios above to see if there is anything different and here is the results:

**URL pasted into webbrowser address bar:**

[image: URL pasted into webbrowser address bar]

**URL embedded into web page:**

[image]

The only differences seems to be the **Accept: Parameters**.

Now to move onto my real problem.  I am using the same url in my C++ curl program and I am seeing the exact same behaviour where I receive video data for a few mins and then all of a sudden the curl callbacks stop.

I have used the following headers in my curl program:

```
CURL *pEasy = curl_easy_init ();
curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_USERNAME, user.c_str() );
curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, pass.c_str() );
curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_URL, urlToConnectTo.c_str() );

//Set authentication
curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );
curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false );

curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE );
curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE );

curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, OnReceiveHttpBodyResponse );
curl_easy_setopt ( pEasy, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, pEasy );

struct curl_slist *headers=NULL; 
curl_slist_append( headers, "User-Agent: MyCurlDll");
curl_slist_append( headers, "Content-Type: text/xml");
curl_slist_append( headers, "Connection: Keep-Alive");
curl_slist_append( headers, "Accept: image/png, text/xml, text/html, application/xml");
curl_slist_append( headers, "Cache-Control: max-age=0");
curl_easy_setopt(pEasy, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

curl_multi_add_handle(m_curlMulti, pEasy);

//Process this curl handle in another function
```

What can I do to stop this behaviour in CURL?  I assume it must be caching is the same way as the browser was doing it.

Comment: I don't know the answer, just some tips:

- Browsers are crap. Say, if you remove an IMG from the DOM, which is playing MJPEG, it keeps receiving MJPEG data (use window.stop() - but it stops _everything_). Another issue: if the FPS of the MJPEG is too high for your computer, the browser still receives it at full speed, and the display will be a mess (lotsa skipped frames, maybe freeze). There is no browser compatiblity issues, all browsers are crap.

- You may play with headers from command-line CURL (don't forget to redirect the result to /dev/null), it's faster than compile-and-try.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but you've ended up with the wrong conclusion and thus you're sort of barking up the wrong tree here.

curl doesn't cache anything, it simply sends a HTTP request to the server (and with CURLOPT_VERBOSE you can easily inspect it) and then it pipes all data it receives on to the write callback that you provide. There's no caching, no middle layers, no magic.

If you stop getting traffic before it should've ended, it is because there's no more data being delivered or rather being received by libcurl. It could be the server that stopped sending or it can be something in your network that interferes. libcurl sent the request and it'll keep waiting for data to arrive until the entire thing has been delivered.